# Unable to display data using *ngFor with keyvalue pipe

Tags: javascript, angular

This is a component.html file and after using | key-value I am unable to display data using key-value pair, can anyone suggest me better approach how to convert object datatype into an array in angular

```
    <div class="slider">
    <div class="slide" *ngFor="let item of items | keyvalue">
        <div class="slide-bg">
            <img class="slide-bg-image" src="path" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="slide-pane">
            <h2 class="name">{{item.title}}: {{item.string}}</h2> // displaying error
        </div>
    </div>
            <div class="meta">
                <div class="info">
                    <span class="rating"><span class="material-icons">star</span><span
                            class="rating-value">7.5/10</span>
                        <span>463 reviews</span>
                        <span>2021</span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="desc mt-5">desc</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Interface

```
export interface Movie {
  adult: boolean;
  backdrop_path: string;
  genre_ids: number[];
  id: number;
  original_language: string;
  original_title: string;
  overview: string;
  popularity: number;
  poster_path: string;
  release_date: string;
  title: string;
  video: boolean;
  vote_average: number;
  vote_count: number;
}
```

This is the Service

```
export class MoviesService {
  movieURL = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/upcoming?api_key=c0f9f2d9cb978825b4fea0898bc2d598';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getMovies() {
    return this.http.get<any>(this.movieURL);
  }
}
```

This is slider component

```
export class SliderComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() items: Movie[] = [];

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

This is Homecomponent.ts

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  movies: any = [];

  constructor(private moviesService: MoviesService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.moviesService.getMovies().subscribe((response) => {
      this.movies = response;
    });
  }
}
```

If "**| keyvalue**" is removed from *ngFor="let item of items | keyvalue" then getting below error,

```
Error: NG0900: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed
    at DefaultIterableDiffer.diff (core.mjs:27563:1)
    at NgForOf.ngDoCheck (common.mjs:3185:42)
    at callHook (core.mjs:2552:1)
    at callHooks (core.mjs:2511:1)
    at executeCheckHooks (core.mjs:2443:1)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:9493:1)
    at refreshComponent (core.mjs:10655:1)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.mjs:9280:1)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:9534:1)
    at refreshComponent (core.mjs:10655:1)
```

Comment: Can you show your items JSON? Also what error is displayed?

Comment: Please add your code. Also don't post code as pictures, this doesn't count.

Comment: @cloned please have a look of the code

Answer (score 0):

home.component.ts

Updated the HomeComponent with this **this.movies = response.results;**

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  movies: any = [];

  constructor(private moviesService: MoviesService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.moviesService.getMovies().subscribe((response) => {
      this.movies = response.results;
    });
  }
}
```

This will solve the problem and no need to use keyvalue pipe as object data is getting converted to array in slider.component.ts

```
export class SliderComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() items: Movie[] = [];

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```